# how to switch from localhost to the internet in jsf

Tags: java

i am using netbeans 8.2, glassfish server, and jsf. i created a small app. Now, i want it to be accessed from other computers via internet.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Deploy the application on _some_ server. This is too broad and general.

Comment: hi @luk2302. i edited my question. do you have the answer?

Comment: google "host glassfish server".

Comment: can someone ask? please ^_^

Comment: thank you very much @luk2302. i google it. i founded that there are people who can do it for me. but, i want to host my app myself. how can i do?

Comment: Google something like "make my computer a server" and be prepared for a couple of days / weeks of work.

Comment: do you know somewhere where i can find good tutorial on that?

Answer (score 0):

## Steps to host jsf application on internet (using open source):

1) obtain leased internet circuit(s) and global unicast ipv6 address(es) or a public ipv4 address(es) from internet service provider(s)
2) register your domain name at a domain registrar
3) buy infrastructure like, app/web server(s), database server(s), aggregation L2/L3 switch(es), router, firewall, rack, air-conditioners, UPS, install and configure them properly
4) install a) operating system like centos 7, b) java application server like payara 4 and c) database like, postgresql 10 and harden them
5) establish perimeter securities
6) code, build the war/ear, test the jsf application in development and testing environment and deploy it in the production(internet), if found suitable.